# Circular reference for entity framework via Entity inside navigation property's list

Tags: entity-framework, json.net

I'm fetching entities with nested entities in navigation properties. Problem is
I've got a `Book` with a navigation property `Borrows` and each `Borrow` has a navigation property `Book` referring back to the book, so there's a circular reference. I guess what I should do is find a way to include a book's Borrow list and in each Borrow not include the reverse reference via the navigation inside that `Borrow.Book`? I'm new to Entity Framework and not sure how to do this, I've heard of load types for navigation properties but I'm not sure if it's suited to this situation.

Similarly, whenever I fetch a list of borrowed books I'd like the Borrow to include the Book but not a list of the borrows in the Book of the Borrow which lead to circular referencing.

**Web API controller `/books`:**

```
public List<Book> GetBooks()
{
    var books = db.Books.ToList();
    return books;
}
```

**Error:**

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
    "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": null,
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "Self referencing loop detected for property 'book' with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Book_6E27A1F717202EA02AE923CCC6405EF9A501FE9A54A71841CEB43E942224D88A'. Path '[0].borrows[0]'.",
        "exceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
        "stackTrace": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution for you here is to have an intermediate structure

Book -> Borrow -> Person
Person -> Borrow list -> Book

Borrow would just have the book details and Person details. Book will be linked to Borrow and not the person/borrower directly. The person will have a collection of Borrow and not linked to Book directly. That way you would resolve the circular reference.